# Let $Ω$ be any sample space, and $A,B$ are subsets of $Ω$ . Which of the following statements are always true?

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $Ω$ be any sample space, and $A, B$ are subsets of $Ω$. Which of the following statements are always true?

1. If $|A|+|B|≥|Ω|$, then $P(A∪B)=1$
2. If $|A|+|B|≥|Ω|$, then $P(A)+P(B)≥1$
3. If $P(A)+P(B)>1$, then $A∩B≠∅$
4. If $P(A)+P(B)>1$, then $P(A∪B)=1$

I would select options 2 and 3, but I struggle to determine how either one of these can hold true or false...

Comment: What does $|A|$ mean for an arbitrary subset $A\subset \Omega$? The cardinality of $A$? The Lebesgue measure of $A$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg (2) is false of course. We could even have $P(A)=P(B)=0$.

Comment: $|A|$ represents the length of set A.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I see now. There is a situation with $|\Omega|=0.$ Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) and (4) are false in general. Just take $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathbb P$ uniformly distributed, take $A = B = \{1,2\}$. Then $\mathbb P(A \cup B) = \frac{2}{3}$, however $|A|+|B| = 4 \ge 3 = |\Omega|$, and $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) = \frac{4}{3} > 1$

(3) is true in general. Note that $\mathbb P(A \cup B) = \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A \cap B)$. If $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) > 1$, then $\mathbb P(A \cap B) $ must be greater than $0$, too, because $\mathbb P(A \cup B) $ cannot be greater than $1$.

About the (2), I must have more information, like is $\Omega$ finite, and $\mathbb P$ uniformly distributed? If so, then answer if yes. But not in general

Comment: For (2), take the same example but $P(3)=1$.

Comment: You are correct. Only 3 is True. $Ω$ can be any sample space, and it can be non-uniform as well.